# How to return file to user and update UI

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

My problem is following:
I have mvc3 project. Problem is in the excel sheet load page. First I want to upload excel sheet to database. Next I create pdf based on that excel sheet and return that pdf to user. Last I want to update rows in ui, that new excel sheet has loaded.

So the main problem is that I cant update rows after passing the pdf-document to user.

This is short example what I tried. First my client side of upload. (I am using Microsoft.Web.Helpers.FileUpload component):

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("NewFile", "LoadData", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
     {      
        @FileUpload.GetHtml(initialNumberOfFiles: 1, allowMoreFilesToBeAdded: false, includeFormTag: false, addText: "Add Files", uploadText: "Upload File")
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Lataa tiedot" />
     }
```

After user has pressed submit button should happen that functionality what I introduced before in my text. This is how I load excel sheet and create pdf-document:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewFile(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> fileUpload, bool checkPrintAlso, bool chkBigCards, int hiddenCustomer, string comment)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var file in fileUpload)
        {
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var excelService = new ExcelService();
                var trackingCodes = excelService.NewLoadData(file, User.Identity.Name, comment, hiddenCustomer);
                if (checkPrintAlso)
                {
                    CreatePdf(trackingCodes, chkBigCards);
                    return new EmptyResult();
                }
            }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", error);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

If I return something else than null or emptyResult pdf does not anymore return to user. This is how I createPdf and write data to response:

```
[HttpPost]
public void CreatePdf(IEnumerable<TrackingCode> trackingCodes, bool isBig)
{
    //This creates pdf
    var blackGinBarCodePdf = new BlackGinBarcodePdf(trackingCodes, isBig);
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "attachment;filename=Receipt-{0}.pdf", "briefcases"));
    Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])blackGinBarCodePdf);
}
```

I have tried to do handling jquery and ajax that I could proceed handling after that pdf document ends up to the user, but when I do for example ajax that posting operation it is not returning succeed message. It will return error code 0 on Mozilla and IE returns code 500(internal server error). This is how I have tried to do post on ajax:

```
$("#submit").click(function () 
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "/LoadData/NewFile",
        type: 'post',
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) 
        {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        },
    success: function (data) { }
    })
    //add row to ui!
    ;
});
```

So hope that someone understand my problem. Once more, Step what I need to do after clicking button.
1. LoadExcel to db
2. Parsing excel to pdf
3. Return pdf to user.
4. update ui
(Problem is updating ui after returning pdf to user)

I really preciated, if someone can help me. Im really confused how can I do that?

Comment: In stead of writing your pdf result to the Response (which is a bit more normal ASP rather than MVC), you may want to use the File method that is provided for Controllers: return File((byte[]) blackGinBarCodePdf, "application/pdf");

Answer (score 0):

You can't return file and some other data in the one response (well, actually you can do it but it won't be correctly handled by browser). Correct way is to:

1. Save your PDF (or just excel) somewhere on the server (filesystem /
   database)
2. Return JSON (or some other result) with result status and some ID of your file
3. Make request from the client (not AJAX, just simple change window.location or post some form to some URL) to some URL with your file ID
4. Return FileResult (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult.aspx) from action for this URL

Comment: It is working that way nicely. Really big thanks both of you. One question still confusing me. Might be that Im little lost with mvc3, but if I return FileResult, how can I return it straight to the user. If I return document just how Rene guide me, it will return it straight to the client window. I want that document will return to users downloading window. (I mean the way, how you downnloading files.) However this is not so important anymore becouse it will work that asp.net style how I wanted to work. Just curious is it to simple to do with fileResult as same way as ASP?

Comment: Try to set this property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult.filedownloadname%28v=vs.98%29.aspx

Comment: Oh my god. This is working also! This really helps my a lot. Thanks!